# Activity started even it have the tag android:protectionLevel="signature"

Tags: android, security, android-intent, certificate, signing

I have 2 application "A" and "B"

Application "A" is signed with certificate C_A and "B" with C_B

in "A"

```
    <activity android:name=".ActivityA" android:protectionLevel="signature" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.temp.packagea" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

in app "B"

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("com.temp.package");
        startActivity(i);
```

and the problem is that the application A is started with no problems from application B.

How can I protect starting activity in my app from application that are signed with the same signature as mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`protectionLevel` is not a valid attribute for an Activity tag within a manifest. The `protectionLevel` tag applies to a `<permission>` element and is used when your application is specifying a new permission (not one of the default Android system permissions).

It looks like you are trying to prevent applications from invoking an `Activity` (A, in your example) if they are not signed with the same certificate as the containing application. What you want to do here is to declare a new permission in the manifest (of the application containing A) by using a `<permission>` element and set the `protectionLevel` of your new permission to `Signature`.   Then, in your manifest declaration for the `Activity`, use an `android:permission` attribute so that this new permission is required to start the `Activity`. For any other application that you want to be able to invoke the `Activity`, you just need to add a `uses-permission` element in that other application's manifest and specify the new permission you created. Since that permission is a `Signature` permission, the system will automatically grant it when the new application is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong usage on android:protectionLevel, should put it in permission node.

Comment: Do you mean something like this  <permission android:name="com.temp.asd"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" /> ?, I tried but still it doesn't work